# Wrong spacing with empheq

Tags: spacing, empheq

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath]{empheq}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0.45,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{cmyk}{0.25,0,0,0}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxM}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxT}

\newcommand*\Yellowbox[2][Formel]{%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{#2}
  \sbox{\mysaveboxT}{\fcolorbox{black}{light-blue}{#1}}
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \parbox[b][\ht\mysaveboxM+0.4\ht\mysaveboxT+0.8\dp\mysaveboxT][b]{%
      \wd\mysaveboxM}{#2}
  }
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{shadecolor}{%
      \makebox[\linewidth]{\usebox{\mysaveboxM}}%
    }%
  }%
  \usebox{\mysaveboxM}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\wd\mysaveboxM][c]{%
      \raisebox{\ht\mysaveboxM-0.5\ht\mysaveboxT
                +0.5\dp\mysaveboxT-0.5\fboxrule}{\usebox{\mysaveboxT}}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box={\Yellowbox[Inverse $3 \times 3$ matrix]}]{equation*}
  \textsf{A}^{-1}
  = \frac{1}{a(ei-fh)+b(fg-di)+c(dh-eg)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      ei-fh & ch-bi & bf-ce\\
      fg-di & ai-cg & cd-af\\
      dh-eg & bg-ah & ae-bd
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why is the contents in the box not horizontally centered inside it?

P.S. I have taken the code from the [`empheq` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mh/empheq.pdf) and modified it a bit.

**Update**

I have a feeling that something has changed in `empheq` because I have used the code above before without and problems.

Comment: It is centered in the space left by the title...

Comment: @karlkoellerI don't follow. There is too little space as the front of the formula compared to after it.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the vertical position...

Comment: You have several unprotected end-of-lines in the definition of `\Yellowbox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several unprotected end-of-lines in the definition of `\Yellowbox`; you have also an overfull box, because you're not taking into account `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath]{empheq}
\usepackage{calc}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0.45,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{cmyk}{0.25,0,0,0}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxM}
\newsavebox{\mysaveboxT}

\newcommand*\Yellowbox[2][Formel]{%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxT}{\fcolorbox{black}{light-blue}{#1}}%
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \parbox[b][\ht\mysaveboxM+0.4\ht\mysaveboxT+0.8\dp\mysaveboxT][b]{%
      \wd\mysaveboxM}{#2}%
  }
  \sbox{\mysaveboxM}{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{shadecolor}{%
      \makebox[\displaywidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{\usebox{\mysaveboxM}}%
    }%
  }%
  \usebox{\mysaveboxM}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\wd\mysaveboxM][c]{%
      \raisebox{\ht\mysaveboxM-0.5\ht\mysaveboxT
                +0.5\dp\mysaveboxT-0.5\fboxrule}{\usebox{\mysaveboxT}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\hrulefill X\par
\begin{empheq}[box={\Yellowbox[Inverse $3 \times 3$ matrix]}]{equation*}
  \textsf{A}^{-1}
  = \frac{1}{a(ei-fh)+b(fg-di)+c(dh-eg)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      ei-fh & ch-bi & bf-ce\\
      fg-di & ai-cg & cd-af\\
      dh-eg & bg-ah & ae-bd
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's apparently more space on the right than on the left, because of the fact that the big parentheses (and `pmatrix`) leave more space. Probably `\displaywidth`, rather than `\linewidth` should be used.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between `\linewidth` and `\displaywidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule`? (THe first actually looks better to me but I'm probably mistaken as ever.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg With `\linewidth` you get an overfull box, so it's hardly “better”; `\displaywidth` is the width TeX maintains for deciding how wide is a displayed equation, which can be or not equal to `\linewidth`.

Comment: Thank you. Assume I have `\linewidth-27em` (i.e., not just `\linewidth`), how do I change this to something involving `\displaywidth`?

Comment: I got it; never mind.