# Change spacing after one empheq environment

Tags: align, amsmath, empheq

I have a boxed equation using `align` in an `empheq` environment like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
M &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h \\
  a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i
  \end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&\hspace{4em} + 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a+b+c & 0 \\
  0 & a+b+c
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

I want to have a smaller vertical spacing between the equation number and boxed equation. How do I do this?

It may be possible to change all the `empheq` environments in the document with suggestions in e.g. [Spacing behavior changes with empheq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185939/spacing-behavior-changes-with-empheq) or [Wrong spacing with empheq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127908/wrong-spacing-with-empheq?rq=1), but I only want to do this for one specific equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boxed equation overflows into the margin. Actually, if you use the `geometry`, so as to have decent outer margins, and the `medmath` command from `nccmath`, there will be no vertical spacing for the equation number. This commands prepares its argument in ‘medium size’ (~ 80 % of `\display style`), and you even can have your equation in a `\widefbox` which looks nicer than `\fbox` for long equations.

Here is a code, with 3 ways to place the equation number. I changed your input encoding to `utf8`, more portable. Loading `amsmath` is unnecessary, since `empheq` does it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} %
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{{\setlength\fboxsep{10pt}\fbox{\hspace{0.5em}#1\hspace{0.5em}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\color{red}\widefbox]{equation}
  M =\!\begin{aligned}[t]
  \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h \\
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i
    \end{bmatrix}} & \\
  + \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c & 0 \\
    0 & a+b+c
    \end{bmatrix}} &
  \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  M =\medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h \\
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i
    \end{bmatrix}} & \\
  + \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c & 0 \\
    0 & a+b+c
    \end{bmatrix}} &
  \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}


\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}
  M = \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h \\
    a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h & a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i
    \end{bmatrix}} &\notag \\
  + \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    a+b+c & 0 \\
    0 & a+b+c
    \end{bmatrix}} &
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]