# Undefined control sequence with empheq package

Tags: packages, undefined

I am new in this community and TeX. I am trying to add some equations in my TeX file with `empheq` package, I assume something is going on with the installation of the package, I am using Kile KDE editor.

These are the packages used:

```
     %% packages
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb} % needed for math fonts
    %\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{amsmath} % needed for command eqref
    %\usepackage{mathtools}
    %\usepackage{algorithm}
    %\usepackage{algorithmic}
    %\usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    %\usepackage{bookmark}
    %\usepackage{algpseudocode}
    %\usepackage{algcompatible}
    %
    \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{alphabeta}

    \usepackage[
        unicode
        ,colorlinks=true
        ,breaklinks
        %,greek
        ]{hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the document, the option colorlinks=true gets rid of the %awful %boxes, breaklinks breaks lonkg links (list of figures), and ngerman sets everything for german as %default hyperlinks %language
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}

    %\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % benötigt für das Brechen von URLs in Literaturreferenzen, hyphenbreaks auch bei %links, die über eine Seite gehen (mit hyphenation).
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    %\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
    %\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} % light blue
    %\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue%
    \hypersetup{
      colorlinks=True,
        linkcolor=blue, % internal links    
        citecolor=green!0.3!blue!0.9,
      urlcolor=red!0.3!blue!0.9} % external links/urls

    \usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{algorithm, algcompatible}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath} 
    %\usepackage{cite}          % needed for cite
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}      % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
    \usepackage[numbers, authoryear]{natbib}    % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliography style
    \usepackage{graphicx}           % needed for \includegraphics 
    \usepackage{bigstrut}           % needed for the command \bigstrut
    \usepackage{enumerate}          % needed for some options in enumerate
    %\usepackage{todonotes}         % needed for todos
    %\usepackage{makeidx}           % needed for creating an index
    %\makeindex
    \newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
      \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}]}
```

This is the main TeX script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}

    \input{settings/packages}
    %\usepackage{algorithm, algcompatible}
    %\usepackage{empheq, nccmath} 
    \algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\textbf{Input:}]}%
    \algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\textbf{Output:}]}%

    %\input{settings/page}
    \graphicspath{{Images/}}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
    %\makeglossaries

    %\input{settings/macros}
    %\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\underline{\textit{#1}}}
    %\input{Contents/abbreviations}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    %\setcitestyle{}
    %\setcounter{page}{4} 
    % Main document Below
    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    %\input{Contents/title_page} 
    \input{abstractGR}
    %\input{abstractEn}

    \pagestyle{plain}
    %\setotherlanguage{greek}
    %\selectlanguage{greek}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \tableofcontents
    \raggedbottom
    %\flushbottom
    %\clearpage\phantomsection
    %\selectlanguage{english}

    \pagebreak
    %\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
    % Insert dedication
    \vspace*{10cm}
    \centering{\large{\emph{\textgreek{ Στην Οικογενειά μου...} }}}
    \vfill
    \pagebreak

    \raggedright
    %\pagestyle{plain}
    %\input{chapters/introduction}
    %\input{chapters/modelSelection}
    %\input{chapters/post_process}
    %\chapter{}
    %\input{chapters/experiments}
    %\input{chapters/conclusion}
    %\appendix
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{}APP}{}{}}
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendix}{}}
    %\input{chapters/appendix}
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Appendix}{}{chapter*.\thepage}}

        %\newpage
        %\chapter{Introduction}

        \medskip
        %\citet*{*}
        %\cite{latexcompanion}
        %\bibliography{thesis}

        %\printindex

    \end{document}
```

abstractGR.tex file that includes `empheq`

```
\chapter*{\centering \textgreek{Περίληψη}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\textgreek{Περίληψη (Ελληνικά)}}{}{chapter*.%\thepage}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract (Greek)}
\textgreek{Η παρούσα διπλωματική εξετάζει το πρόβλημα της αναγνώρισης αντικειμένων από εικόνες, των οποίων τα πίξελ είναι ταξινομημένα σε μια από τις 19 κατηγορίες. Η εργασία χρησιμοποιεί μια βάση δεδομένων που αποτελείται από 19 διαφορετικές κατηγοριές αντικειμένων η οποία έχει δημιουργηθεί με χρήση κάμερας τοποθετημένη στο εμπρόσθιο μέρος του αυτοκινήτου. Οι εικόνες έχουν απαθανατιστεί από 50 διαφορετικές πόλεις της Ευρώπης σε διάφορες εποχές και καιρικές συνθήκες.\\

Με την χρήση πληροφορίας από εικόνες κατασκευάζουμε έναν ταξινομηττή ο οποίος μπορεί να αναγνωρίσει την κατηγορία αντικειμένων που ανήκει το κάθε πίξελ στην εικόνα ως συνάρτηση του μεγέθους των pixel αλλά και της δομής που απεικονίζουν. Για την ταξινόμηση χρησιμοποιήσαμε 2 πανομοιότυπα μοντέλα πλήρως συνελικτικών νευρωνικών δικτύων (}FCNNs\textgreek{) σε συνδυασμό με 2 διαφορετικά μοντέλα μετά επεξεργασίας. Το πρώτο μοντέλο κάνει χρήση του Μέσου Φίλτρου(}Median Filter\textgreek{), ενώ το δεύτερο κάνει χρήση μιας παραλλαγής του στατιστικού μοντέλου }CRF. \textgreek{Για την εικονοποίηση των παραπάνω αποτελεσμάτων υλοποιήθηκε λογισμικό που απεικονίζει τα αποτελέσματα των μεθόδων. Για την κατασκευή των παραπάνω μοντέλων γίνεται χρήση των βιβλιοθηκών }Scikit-learn, Keras \textgreek{ και} Tensorflow, \textgreek{ ενώ για την υλοποίηση του λογισμικού εικονοποίησης έγινε η χρήση της βιβλιοθήκης} pyQt.


\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract (English)}{}{chapter*.\thepage}}

This thesis focuses the problem of recognizing objects from images whose images are classified in one of the 19 categories. The job uses a database consisting of 19 different categories of objects created using a camera located on the front of the car. Images have been recorded in 50 different European cities in different seasons and weather conditions.

Using information from images, we construct a classifier that can recognize the category of objects belonging to each image of the image as a function of the size of the pixels and the structure they represent. For classification, we used 2 identical Fully Convolutional Neural Networks in combination with 2 different models after editing. The first model uses Median Filter), while the latter uses a variation of the CRF statistical model. To illustrate the above results, we have implemented software that illustrates the results of the methods. To build the above models, we use Scikit-learn, Keras and Tensorflow, while using pyQt libraries.

\begin{empheq}{align} 
    \mathit{Loss(P,Q)} &= - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times 
    \log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{\mathit{coefficients}}\\
    \nabla\times\overline{E}\notag
     &= -\frac{\partial\overline{B}}{\partial t}-\bar J_{\text{mi}} 
\end{empheq}
```

The `empheq` call is in the chapter `abstractGR.tex` from the one above, if I move the packages from the `packages.tex` to `main.tex` works like a charm.

Comment: In addition to what @daleif is saying, could you check if some random MWE using `empheq`, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328058/121799), runs through?

Comment: @marmot Yes, your example you linked is working...

Comment: Well, why don't you just adapt it, throw out unnecessary style files and replace the stuff between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` by your equation? Either it works or, if it does not work, people will have an MWE.

Comment: `emphes` requires an argument:  the name of a maths environment. You have commented out `{align}` in your code.

Comment: @Bernard I did this temporarily to test if the problem was with the align option. Even with the arguments uncommented, still doesn't works...

Comment: instead of `locate` use `kpsewhich empheq.sty` and, of course, use `listfiles` as first line in your document.

Comment: @Herbert If there was a problem with `empheq.sty` location, why would the random example then work for the OP, and wouldn't he get a different error message then?

Comment: I think the reason that the package empheq is not working in documentclass{book}, is there another option to work with book class?

Comment: Your above MWE is lacking the line `\usepackage{empheq}` (at least). Is that on purpose?

Comment: you have not used the package so empheq is not defined (unless that is just an error constructing your small example?)

Comment: I had a small sample only, now i have the whole package script, i guess some other package does the job...

Comment: Yes, there are option clashes. But these are independent of empheq, I think.

Comment: if you want help with an error you should post an example that generates the error the code that you have posted so far is missing `\documentclass` so can not be tested (the second fragment has `\documentclass` but that doesn't use any of the packages so will naturally give the undefined command error)

Comment: Remember to remove the two % on the line with `\begin{empheq} `

Comment: Well, i isolated the chapter which has the empheq call with the main script and it works, but still it doesn't work within the whole project... I don't know what is going on... Environment Undefined comes up only when the definition of the package is missing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok problem solved. In my main.tex file i have a packages.tex included in the main's preamble, i put the `\usepackage{empheq}` command in the main script and it worked. Is there any explanation about this behavior, it should work from an input tex file, right?

Comment: @Dimmal13 you need to include `empheq` package to use the environment, that is all I can say. You have not shown any example that includes the package and does not work so I can not say what is wrong. Perhaps you don't include `packages.tex` in your document (as in the case of the example you posted here) or perhaps it has `\endinput` half way down and empheq was added after that, how can we guess?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, `packages.tex` was included otherwise i would have other errors as well. I had the package `empheq` included in my `packages.tex` file. Anyway, the problem is solve, i am just curious about the reason why this problem occurred. I will add these two scripts to check if you want.

Comment: If you post a document which generates an error someone will be able to tell you why the error occurs. If you don't then they can't:-) Or you could just accept one of the existing examples to get the question off the list of open questions and call it done, up to you...

Comment: you have edited the example so that it is now no use at all. the example needs to be something that people can run to debug the error.

Comment: `\centering{\large{\emph{\textgreek{ Στην Οικογενειά μου...} }}}` will make your _whole document_ use unjustified centred text, is that what you intended?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have re-edited the file, i think now should be ok for testing. Well, i need to put in the center of the page these words, any better suggestions?

Comment: it does not give an undefined command error it gives `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`

Comment: you need to use `\centering` just in a local scope not apply it to the whole document or use `\begin{center}..\end{center}`

Comment: your document runs without error if you replace the non standard `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` by the standard `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Document class book works fine.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    \mathit{Loss(P,Q)} &= - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times 
    \log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{\mathit{coefficients}}\\
    \nabla\times\overline{E}\notag
     &= -\frac{\partial\overline{B}}{\partial t}-\bar J_{\text{mi}} 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I stole the `{\mathit{coefficients}` from @Zarko and replaced `\bar` by `\overline` because IMHO this looks better.

**SECOND UPDATE**: Your code had several option clashes. I think I solved all of them apart from those associated to babel and greek, which I never was able to run on my machine. For instance, you do not need definecolor in order to set the link etc. colors.

```
\documentclass{book}
%% packages
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for command eqref
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[unicode,
    ,colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
%    ,greek
    ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=green!0.3!blue!0.9
  urlcolor=red!0.3!blue!0.9}
%\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
%%%
% \usepackage{} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % benötigt für das Brechen von URLs in Literaturreferenzen, hyphenbreaks auch bei %links, die über eine Seite gehen (mit hyphenation).
 % needed for creating hyperlinks in the document, the option colorlinks=true gets rid of the %awful %boxes, breaklinks breaks lonkg links (list of figures), and ngerman sets everything for german as %default hyperlinks %language
% \definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
% \definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} % light blue
% \definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue
% \hypersetup{
%     linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
%     citecolor={c2}, % citations
%     urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
% }

%

\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[numbers, authoryear]{natbib}    % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliography style
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}      % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx}           % needed for \includegraphics 
\usepackage{bigstrut}           % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate}          % needed for some options in enumerate
% \newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
%   \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}]}
% 

    \begin{document}        
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
            \mathit{Loss(P,Q)} = - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{coefficients}
            \nabla\times\bar E &= -\frac{\partial\bar B}{\partial t}-\bar J_{\text{mi}} 
        \end{empheq}
    \end{document}


    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    \mathit{Loss(P,Q)} &= - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times 
    \log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{\mathit{coefficients}}\\
    \nabla\times\overline{E}\notag
     &= -\frac{\partial\overline{B}}{\partial t}-\bar J_{\text{mi}} 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did not massage the equation here because I'm afraid of @Zarko ;-)

Comment: @marmot This is what i want to, i have updated the script, i guess some package conflicts with empheq...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{empheq, amssymb}
```

\usepackage[
     unicode,
    ,colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
%    ,greek % <--- my instalation doesn't suport mee
    ]{hyperref}

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\mathit{Loss}(P,Q)  & = - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times \log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{\mathit{coefficients}}  \\
\nabla\times\bar{E} & = - \frac{\partial\bar{B}}{\partial t}-\bar{J}_{\mathrm{mi}}
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
\end{empheq}
```

gives

[image]

is this what you looking for?

errors in your code snippet:

- `emheq` had to have defined math style, which define fomr of equation (`align˙, which you comment out)
- after first equation you forget on `\\`
- i susspect that before equal sign in the first equation is missing ampersand
- more correct is `\bar{E}`˛then `\bar E` etc
- instead `\text{mi}` is correct `\mathrm{mi}`

**edit:**
above mwe also works with `hyperref` package (i load it as last in preamble) compiled with `xelatex`.

Comment: I also updated the document class faster than you;-) And I adapted the `\mathit{coefficients}` from your answer, if that's OK with you, if not, I remove it. And I did not bit you, neither bite (since I am vegetarian) but beat. ;-)

Comment: well, please not beat me :-). you just use anything from my answer what you find valuable. now  i'm not sure (anymore), if i understood question correct :-(. anyway, here it is an will left it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You get an option clash for `hyperref` as you load `bookmark` at the start with no options, and that loads `hyperref`, so whenyou later load hyperref you get an error.

If you fix that by moving `bookmarks` then you get an error that `hyperref` does not have a `greek` option. Finally there is an error in the document that `empheq` requires an enviornment passed as the first option.

```
   \documentclass{book}
 %% packages
%\usepackage{xgreek}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for command eqref
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{algcompatible}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[toc, appendix]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%%% Testt
%\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[
     unicode,
    ,colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
%    ,greek
    ]{hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the document, the option colorlinks=true gets rid of the %awful %boxes, breaklinks breaks lonkg links (list of figures), and ngerman sets everything for german as %default hyperlinks %language
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % benötigt für das Brechen von URLs in Literaturreferenzen, hyphenbreaks auch bei %links, die über eine Seite gehen (mit hyphenation).
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}

%

\usepackage{alphabeta}
%\usepackage{cite}          % needed for cite
\usepackage[numbers, authoryear]{natbib}    % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliography style
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}      % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx}           % needed for \includegraphics 
%\usepackage{longtable}             % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut}           % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate}          % needed for some options in enumerate
%\usepackage{todonotes}         % needed for todos
%\usepackage{makeidx}           % needed for creating an index
%\makeindex
\newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
  \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}]}
    \begin{document}        
    \begin{empheq}{align}%[left=\empheqlbrace]%{align}
            \mathit{Loss(P,Q)} = - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x}^{N} P(x)\times log(Q(x)) \times \alpha_{coefficients}
            \nabla\times\bar E &= -\frac{\partial\bar B}{\partial t}-\bar J_{\text{mi}} 
        \end{empheq}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Even with the align environment the problem resists...

Comment: @daleif When i uncomment the greek package in hyperref in David's MWE i get the following error: 

! Package keyval Error: greek undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4319 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
                                 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def

Comment: @Dimmal13 yes exactly that is what I said, you get an error in the code that you posted as hyperref does not have a greek option, that is why I commented it out.

Comment: We asked you whether David's example works on your system. Don't change it. Then you are basically wasting the time of the people trying to help you.

Comment: @Dimmal13 what do you mean by "the problem resists" ? the code I posted here runs without error. If you get an error then show the exact error that you get.

Comment: Indeed the code from @DavidCarlisle runs without an error. I still can't find a way to import empheq without problems to my script. My tex project consists of many files, how i supposed to upload them?

Comment: @Dimmal13 does your document include `\usepackage{empheq}` if it does it is hard to see how you can get the undefined command error that you mention. if it does not, then add it.  To make an example start from a copy of your real document and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the error, once you have something small enough to post her, add it to your question.